# If $f$ is twice differentiable and $f(2^{-n}) = 0 $, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, then $f^\prime(0) = f^{\prime\prime}(0) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function, such that $f(2^{-n}) = 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ . Show that $$f^\prime(0) = f^{\prime\prime}(0) = 0.$$

**My attempt.** 
First, let us show that $f(0) = 0$ . Since $f$ is twice differentiable, it is also continuous. Suppose $f(0) = k$ where $k \ne 0$ . Then there is a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$ , $f(x) \in (k/2,3k/2)$ . But $f(2^{-n}) = 0 $ for all positive integer values of $n$ . Thus we have a contradiction as no $\delta$ works for $f$ to be continuous at $x=0$ . Thus $f(x) = 0$.

$f(x)$ is differentiable , thus $f^\prime(x)$ is continuous. Suppose $f^\prime (0) = m$ such that $m\neq0$ , then by continuity of $f^\prime(x)$ there is a $\delta$ such that whenever $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$ , $f^\prime(x) \in (m/2,3m/2)$ . Choose an $N$ such that 
$2^{-N} < \delta$  . Now, $\int_{x=0}^{1/2^N} f^\prime(x) = f(2^{-N}) - f(0) = f(2^{-N})$ (I am confused whether this integral exists or not ,as in if $f^\prime(x)$ is integrable or not in the interval I am using) . Now $\int_{x=0}^{1/2^N} f^\prime(x) > m/2(1/2^N)$ as the integral would be greater than the rectangle formed using a lower bound for the value of $f$ in the interval. Thus  $\int_{x=0}^{2^{-N}} f^\prime(x) > 0$ and thus $f(2^{-N}) > 0$ but this is a contradiction as $f(2^{-N}) = 0$ by the function definition. Thus we have a contradiction and thus, $f^\prime(0)$ can't be non-zero.

We can proceed similarly to prove that $f^{\prime\prime}(0) = 0$ .

Is my approach correct, is there a better way to prove it ?  I am not sure if my solution is correct as I am not sure of using integrals the way I used it. Thanks.

Comment: "$f$ is differentiable , thus $f′$ is continuous" is *false* in general. True in *this* case, because $f'$ is differentiable. I think that $f''$ continuous is required.

Comment: So this approach can't be used to prove $f^{\prime\prime}(0) = 0$ . But the approach works for $ f^\prime(0) = 0 $ ? I don't recall it was given in the question that the double differential is continuous. Can it be solved without using that ?

Comment: If the function is twice differentiable, you can use its [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem): $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}2f''(0)+x^2h(x)$, where function $h$ has a limit $\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach can be fixed. This can be also shown using the Mean Value Theorem (MVT).

Using MVT, we obtain that
$$
0=f(2^{-n})-f(2^{-n-1})=2^{-n-1}f'(x_n), 
$$
for some $x_n\in (2^{-n-1},2^{-n})$. Thus we can define $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, such that $x_n\to 0$ with $f'(x_n)=0$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which implies by the continuity of $f'$, that
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f'(x_n)=0.
$$

Since $f'$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and $x_n\to 0$, then
$$
0=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f'(x_n)-f'(0)}{x_n}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}=
f''(0).
$$

**Note.** If it was given that $f$ was $k$ times differentiable, then this method explained above, would provide that $f^{(j)}(0)=0$, for all $j=1,2,\ldots,k$.

Comment: I saw the question in an exam I appeared  , I don't remember if the double differential is given to be continuous. Can it be solved without it ?

Comment: The continuity of $f''$ isn't given. But you have $$\frac{f'(x_n) - f'(0)}{x_n} = 0,$$ and the existence of $f''(0)$ says $$f''(0) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f'(x_n)-f'(0)}{x_n} = 0.$$ (@ameyask86)

Comment: Can I use the existence of $f^\prime(0)$ and $f^{\prime\prime}(0)$ , in my approach too ? I mean in my approach I don't think I need to have continuity of the double derivative , as I too am using just the fact that the limits exist . I mean , the continuity condition is not needed in my approach also. Of course , the approach provided in this answer is quite succinct as compared to the one I used. Thanks.